# Can a pic drive a 5 volt relay directly without a transistor switch?

Tags: pic, relay

Can for example [this microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262d.pdf) drive [this relay](http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/ds_61005_en_ds2y.pdf) without additional circuitry, now I read a bit and I know that the current required by the 5 volt relay (40 mA) is more than what can be sunk by a single pin(25 mA) so can I connect all pins of port A for example to sink enough current for the relay.

Comment: You can connect the pin in parallel, but you need to toggle them on the same clock cycle, i.e. with a single ASM instruction. And you need a protection diode anyway.

Comment: Why use such an old microcontroller? The newer models have pins which can drive up to 100mA from a single pin. Look e.g. at 16F1619 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001770A.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current (from or to) an output pin will move that pin voltage away from 5 V (if a source) or 0 V (if it's a sink). If you look at section 17.4 it shows this: -

[image]

If you are sinking a current of (say) 8 mA then you will drop a maximum of 0.6 volts. So, with 5 outputs each contributing 8 mA you might see a voltage across the relay coil of about 4.4 volts instead of 5 volts.

Given that the relay needs 70% of 5 volts at ambient temperatures this should work but, watch the maximum dissipation because 40 mA x 0.6 volts is 24 mW lost and if you are planning on driving a few relays this become problematic. Also keep an eye on the peak current into Vdd and 0V pins - this can also be a limiting factor.

Don't forget the diode!

---

It's also worth mentioning that with only 4.4 volts applied, the current through the relay will be smaller than 40 mA so, given that there are a few ifs and buts, you might see in excess of 4.6 volts but there's no guarantee you'll see above 4.4 volts unless you can find a graph of IO current in the data sheet that gives more detail.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at a typical PIC data sheet suggests that the answer is "yes". As Vladimir Cravero says, all I/O pins *must be* switched at once. And the feeble internal diode is insufficient to clamp the relay's flyback transient - an external diode must direct the 40mA current transient back to Vdd. Ensure that there's enough power supply capacitance to absorb this transient without over-volting the PIC Vdd supply pin. It might be wise to run Vdd at a slightly less-than-max (5v) voltage to prevent an over-volt transient on Vdd.
From the "typical" data sheet, maximum current at Vdd pin and at Vss pin was in excess of 100mA, so 40 mA relay current should be OK. Be aware that Vss pin must pass both PIC operating current as well as relay current. A skinny or long path back to the supply-bypass capacitor might cause problems.
Since PIC output pins look like a resistor of about 75 ohms (worst case) when they're active, three or four should roughly share current when working in concert (parallel). It would make sense to parallel all from the same port, since all output drivers should be similar-enough to share so that none exceed 25 mA.
Summary: add the external fast flyback diode. Add a beefier supply bypass capacitor with low ESR. Drive Vdd with a high voltage, but not so high that the flyback transient exceeds max_Vdd spec.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you do not attempt to drive a relay directly from the output pins. A single FET or BJT and resistor would seem an inexpensive addition.

You could connect multiple pins from the same register together to drive the realy, but cannot guarantee they will current share evenly. You'd have to connect at least three pins together to get away with this (using 5 V relay @40mA).
From the datasheet:
[image]

You have to also recognize that the total current for all ports must not exceed 200 mA.

...and as from Vladimer's comment you need to ensure that you write the data value directly and don't manipulate pins serially. If you connect multiple pins together and end up with them in opposite states you could destroy your MCU.

One thought would be to use a 3 V relay @67 mA and use a schottcky diode from each of four ports. This would prevent interactions between I/O pins, and you still need to ensure you set the pins all at once. You still need a fourth diode across the relay coil of course. Of course this uses more components than adding a FET so you don't really gain anything.

Comment: I think I will go for the transistor setup after all but I didn't get the part about pins of the same port sharing current evenly, can you explain more .

Comment: There are differences between every transistor in the output ports, so the current flow and saturation voltage from each port will be different (different R(DS). If you asked two pins set low for example to share 40 mA (Absolute maximum rating) would they? They would not and so one port pin would be over it's absolute maximum rating. You could test the differences even lightly loaded by using a 1k Ohm load to ground and measuring the voltages.

Comment: An output FET with more current would heat up more, which would reduce the current.

Comment: You are absolutely right the RDS(on) has a positive temperature coefficient: http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/14692-mosfet-tutorial    All the FETs (in parallel) will heat up and as they are thermally close together on the same chip, those with the highest highest RDS(on) will take less current as the temperature increases, so increasing any imbalance.